# Faulting application w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a application written in ASP.NET which uses DllImport to reference a dll
written in Delphi. On my Windows 7 dev machine using the asp.net Development Server accessing the ddl works as expected.

However on a Windows Server 2008 Production Server running IIS 7 the dll return the error "Page cannot be found" and the following error pops into the Application log:

```
Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e023cf, faulting
module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e03821, exception code
0xc0000374, fault offset 0x000afaf8, process id 0xab8, application start time   
0x01cc6947b1bb081b.
```

How to solve this or how can I find a deeper cause?

Comment: In your dev environment, did you try running your app in your local IIS as opposed to using the Development Server? Remember, the Development Web Server runs under your credentials so the application permissions are quire different when you run it in IIS. See if running in IIS locally also raises the error.

Comment: Running the application localy on IIS raises also the error.

Comment: so you are making progress... you now now that it has to do with some sort of permission or trust level issue since IIS on your local box also raises the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just a hunch but you could try [enabling 32bit worker process](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/). It's more compatible that 64bit and might help. Is your local server 32bit?

```
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

Failing that this might help debug the issue.

[Troubleshooting IIS7 Worker Thread Crashes (w3wp.exe) with a Faulting Module of ntdll.dll](http://fromthefiefdom.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/troubleshooting-an-iis-w3wpexe-crash-with-ntd/)

There's also a thread here with an identical issue. They suggest that adding a reference to `kernel32.dll` resolved the issue.

[Calling unmanaged code from ASP.NET in IIS7](http://www.ureader.com/msg/152410709.aspx)

**Update**

Some people report that copying your dependencies to `Windows\System32\Inetsrv` resolves the issue. It's worth a try.

Comment: I enabled the 32bit worker procces but no success, my windows 7 is 64bit

Comment: It was worth a shot, `exception code 0xc0000374` means heap corruption.

Comment: Just doing some more reading on this, it seems a lot of people have problems calling unmanaged code in IIS7.

Comment: Failed to find the RegisterModule entrypoint in the module DLL C:\..\Fan.dll. The data is the error. While enabeling a Native Module

Comment: How do I set the entrypoint? and wich entrypoint do I use. Opening the DLL with Dependency Walker gave me a list with entrypoints per function...

Comment: I think the documentation must be referring specially to IIS modules, rather that all unmanaged referenced by the app. There is no entry point because the dll you have is not an unmanaged IIS dll, so forget this option as a fix. Did you try the other options, can you give me access the the dll?

Comment: Another possible solution copy your dll and dependencies into the \System32\Inetsrv directory folder.